# How can I make a file date modified static (not changeable)?

Tags: file-transfer, file-permissions, mp3, media, mtp

I want to sort the songs in my phone by date.

The sort option that's available in my phone is on picture.. But the file modified time gets changed when i copy the songs to my phone and in the properties of the file there isn't a date created.. so is there a way to lock the modified time of a file?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/download) and add the files to the program

click on add method button then select script
then add this to script tab and click apply but make sure that mp3 files are in a short path just like

C:\Users\ttttC\Desktop

and now click start batch

you just can sort the files by name now they will be sorted by the date modified

till you rename them again !

```
var maxLength = 210;
var name = item.name;
var date = app.parseTags("<Year Modified><Month Modified><Day Modified>");
var numSpaces = maxLength - name.length - date.length;
var spaces = "";
for (i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++) spaces += " ";
return name + spaces + date;
```